# Why does ^D (to exit a user) make Bash think I'm breaking out of a loop?

Tags: bash, loops, control-characters

I log into an Ubuntu server as one user, and then `su` to an app-specific user to manage a Rails app.  When I'm done and want to log out, it is normally convenient to enter <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, but on this particular machine, I get a very odd error message:

```
bash: break: only meaningful in a `for', `while', or `until' loop
```

What would cause Bash to think I'm inside a loop trying to `break` out?

This only happens with the "inner" (app-specific) user, not the "outer" user.

`bind -X` does not show any custom key bindings for the app-specific user.

I didn't notice this before, but `exit` has the same problem.

The app-specific user has a `~/.bash_logout` file with

```
if [ "$SHLVL" = 1 ]; then
    [ -x /usr/bin/clear_console ] && /usr/bin/clear_console -q
fi
```

Comment: does `exit` work for you? only ctrl-d has the problem?

Comment: @pynexj actually `exit` does it too... I didn't notice that before... updating question

Comment: does the user have `~/.bash_logout`?

Comment: @yes, but I think it's a default configuration.... I'll post it..

Comment: try `set -x; exit` and see whats happening.

Comment: it did the same thing

Comment: anything outputted on screen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230829/discussion-between-iconoclast-and-pynexj).